# Typo3: don't display language link if no translation available

Tags: menu, typo3, typoscript

I have this typoscript language menu:

```
tmpl.NavLang  = HMENU
tmpl.NavLang {
  special=language
  special.value = 0,1,2,3

  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    NO = 1
    NO {
      stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
      stdWrap.override = DE || EN || FR || PL
      ATagTitle = Deutsch || English || Francais || Polski
    }
    ACT < .NO
    ACT.doNotLinkIt = 1
    ACT.linkWrap = <span>|</span>
  }
}
```

If I am on a page in English which, for example, does not have a French translation, I want to hide FR from the menu.
Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From tsref:

> When TSFE->sys_language_uid matches the sys_language uid for an element the state is set to ACT, otherwise NO. However, if a page is not available due to the pages Localization settings (which can disable translations) or if no Alternative Page Language record was found (can be disabled with .normalWhenNoLanguage, see below) the state is set to USERDEF1 for non-active items and USERDEF2 for active items. So in total there are four states to create designs for. It is recommended to disable the link on menu items rendered with USERDEF1 and USERDEF2 in this case since they are disabled exactly because a page in that language does not exist and might even issue an error if tried accessed (depending on site configuration).

So you just need to read the [manual](https://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/references/doc_core_tsref/4.5.1/view/1/7/#id2634233) and configure the item states for `USERDEF1` and `USERDEF2`. In your case, you would have to override them with an empty value.

Comment: I didn't know about these 2 states. Thanks, pgampe.

Comment: This might be a trivial question from someone who's using TypoScript for the first  time, but how do I override them with an empty value?

Comment: Maybe ``USERDEF1 = 0`` is enough?

Answer (score -2):

Fixed by installing sr_language_menu extension and setting "showInactive" constant to 0.